# Why does a URL say it's taken when it's doesn't acknowledge anything is there?

Tags: url

I'm looking at buying a URL before I do a trip to a third world country, and was wondering why I can't see a URL that appears to be registered, but the URL doesn't acknowledge existence when going to it.

Comment: I always check the owner information on [who.is](http://who.is). They might be willing to part with it for a price...

Answer (score 2):

A URL can be purchased but that doesn't necessarily mean that there's an IP associated with it or a server actually communicating on the other side of that connection.

Comment: isn't parking against ICANN rules though? If so how do you challenge it?

Comment: @acoder - You can't challenge it, and no, it is not against the ICANN rules.  I currently own a domain that doesn't go anywhere.  Touch luck getting that domain from mean, since owner information, is also withheld.

Comment: Not only is parking not against the rules, it doesn't even need to be parked.  Pay the fee, it's yours to use or not.... Until it expires.